# Como hacer un confirm de javascript dentro de php

Tags: php, javascript

Hola buenas tengo una duda, como puedo hacer un `confirm` de `JavaScript` dentro de `php` para que cuando borre, no borre directamente sino que pregunte. No adjunto el código `html` ni el `css` ni el `JavaScript` utilizado ya que es una duda muy específica. Saludos :D.

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['baja'])) {
  if(confirm('Deseas borrarlo?')){
    unset($_SESSION['personas']);
    $mensaje = 'Todo borrado';
  }
  else {
  //No hacer nada
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Respuesta corta **NO PUEDES**, respuesta larga **NO PUEDES PEEEEEERO** podrías conseguir lo que necesitas sin tener que pasar por **PHP** cambiando la lógica de tu código.

Realmente lo que necesitas es que cuando el usuario pulse el botón de borrar le salte el `confirm()` y en caso de de que se acepte dicho `confirm()` se lance el borrado 
. Para ilustrarte te dejo un pequeño ejemplo realizado con Jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#borrar').click(function () {
    let confirmacion = confirm('¿Estás seguro de que quieres borrar?');
    
    if (confirmacion) {
      console.log('Llamas a la función PHP que se encarga del borrado ya sea mediante AJAX o realizando el submit del formulario o como lo tengas montado');
    }
    else {
      console.log('No haces nada o lo que quieras hacer si el usuario decide finalmente no borrar');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="borrar">Borrar</button>
```

**Solución con uso de modal en vez de con confirm()**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#borrar').click(function () {
    $('.modal').modal('show');
  });
  
  $('.btn').click(function () {
    let eleccion = $(this).attr('id');
    
    if(eleccion == 'si') {
     console.log('Llamas a la función PHP que se encarga del borrado ya sea mediante AJAX o realizando el submit del formulario o como lo tengas montado');
     $('.modal').modal('hide');
    }
    else {
      console.log('No haces nada o lo que quieras hacer si el usuario decide finalmente no borrar');
    }
  })
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="borrar">Borrar</button>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Borrar</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>¿Estás seguro de que deseas borrar?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="si" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Si</button>
        <button id="no" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para esta segunda solución me he apoyado en el uso de **Bootstrap**.

Comment: lo unico que añadiria, algunos navegadores tienen el bloqueo de alertas , entonces si se algun usuario bloquea los alertas no veria el mensaje

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. Iba a añadir que no se usan este tipo de mensajes del navegador para comunicarse con el usuario, si no que se relega la tarea en ventanas modales o algo similar, pero no quería extenderme demasiado planteando un ejemplo de esto también.

Comment: Editada para añadir el uso de una modal en vez del `confirm()`

Comment: eliminemos comentarios!